# JQuery if $(this) contains x and does not contain y

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside an each loop, I need to add a class if the current element contains an img not anything else. Here's my latest iteration of not working code, which --- though not right --- probably gives you the idea anyway.

```
$(".details").each(function(index){
 $(this).has("img").not(:contains("p, ul, ol, div, span")).addClass('screenshot-only');
});
```

Obviously I'm trying to exclude `this` if it also contains any of `p, ul, ol, div, span` -- so helping me fix that would be great.

If there's a way to select `if this has only img and nothing else at all`, that would be better.

Comment: You could count the number of children == 1 and then check if it's an img, something like `$(this).children().length == 1 && $(">img", this).length == 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:contains("p, ul, ol, div, span")` should go into quotes since the [Sizzle Engine](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#other-selectors-and-conventions) will parse it as String:

```
':contains(p, ul, ol, div, span)'
```

but that's most likely **not your main issue here**,  `:contains` if you [read the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) searches for TEXT, not DOM nodes

rather take a look at **https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/** or https://api.jquery.com/has/

**A quick way** would be using it in combination with **https://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/**

```
$(".details:has(img:only-child)").addClass("screenshot-only");
```

**Example**

```js
$(".details:has(img:only-child)").addClass("screenshot-only");
```

```css
.screenshot-only {background: gold;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="details">
  <img src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
</div>

<div class="details">
  <img src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
  <p>foo</p>
</div>

<div class="details">
  <img src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
</div>
```

or if you rather want to **target such images** instead:

```js
$(".details:has(img:only-child)").find("img").addClass("screenshot-only");
```

```css
.screenshot-only {border: 5px solid gold;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="details">
  <img src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
</div>

<div class="details">
  <img src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
  <p>foo</p>
</div>

<div class="details">
  <img src="//placehold.it/40x40/0bf">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$(".details").each(function(index){
    $(this).has("img:first-child:last-child").addClass('screenshot-only');
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcoq499w/1/)

Edit: As pointed out in other posts, you can also use `:only-child` selector instead of `:first-child:last-child`. Moreover, you can simply get rid of the `each` if you just want to add a class to each matching element as [Roko C. Buljan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48470865/9135269) shows.

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't attached to jQuery with plain javascript which that is all jQuery is you can do a test for it via:

```
`if (this.contains("img")) {
return;   // doesn't do anything
} else {
$(this).addClass('screenshot-only');
}
` is much easier and is 5 lines using the DOM.
// then just
```